# How to implement SwipeRefreshLayout with GridView/ListView without getting views cut off?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

If I don't set OnScrollListener as bellow, top views in the ListView get cut off after scrolling to the bottom of the list and then up.

Setting OnScrollListener as below seems to work but it seems strange that this is required. I would expect Google to have fixed this without having tot set this listener. Any ideas?

```
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (firstVisibleItem == 0 && visibleItemCount > 0 && absListView.getChildAt(0).getTop() >= 0) {
                mSwipeToRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mSwipeToRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across similar situation and overriding `canChildScrollUp` method fixed it for me. Simply use following when you'd use a `SwipeRefreshLayout` containing a `ListView` or `GridView` with id `android.R.id.list`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


/**
 * Date: 09/02/2014
 * @author: rax
 */
public class ScrollableSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    public ScrollableSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollableSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        // Condition to check whether scrollview reached at the top while scrolling or not
        return findViewById(android.R.id.list).canScrollVertically(-1);
    }
}
```